# Chrome. No matter what I do, user agent stylesheet overwrites border. How do I remove border?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, fireworks

[image: screenshot]

I carved this simple newsletter from fireworks and no matter what I do the user agent stylesheet for border remains.

I've even tried inline styles (screenshot) and still it failed to overwrite the user agent stylesheet.

How do I remove borders from my table?

Also tried reset.css

Code is here [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ShkdhKns)

Larger screenshot here [Large Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idqsa.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: This image doesn't show us what the CSS looks like or what you've tried. Post some code.

Comment: Sorry about that. Code added. @isherwood

Comment: Not what I had in mind. I see a wall of HTML and not much CSS. Post the relevant bits of CSS *in your question*. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: <table style="display: inline-table; border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">

Comment: Did you tried setting css to td?

Comment: @XTG tried that. That was what I tried last before popping border="0" inline.

Comment: Could you throw it up on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @isherwood That teeny bit of css is the only bit of css. It's supposed to be a quick hack from fireworks. Nothing fancy so I thought I'd just fix the borders and pop it into mailchimp ...

Comment: @gaynorvader done. without the images http://jsfiddle.net/fLVkS/1/

Comment: can you post spacer.gif , i am confused with this gif.

Comment: @XTG it's a 1x1 pixel white pixel

Comment: sorry dear but i can't find gif(1x1) in the image

Answer (score 0):

You are using tables for the layout, this is completely wrong and heavy outdated. Tables are only for listing items and not for the general structure/layout!

Try to rebuild the layout with proper HTML/CSS!

Comment: Proper HTML/CSS is not YET the normal practice for email templates.

Comment: You are right with that, I didn't know you are creating mail templates. :-( Can you provide us with full css and html?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the css `border` property instead of the border attribute.

`table{ border:none;}`